# Cpu usage and serialization at each worker

Tags: apache-storm

Q1) is there a serialization in a single worker? When spout emits tuple to bolt in a same worker, is tuple serialized or serialization just takes place among workers and how?

Q2)For 500 message in a second, when single thread is used, CPU usage is approximately between 7% and 10%. The same process takes 130% CPU usage, in our topology. Our topology consist of 3 nodes as one spout --> bolt ----> bolt. Is that normal, what behavior do we have to observe? By the way, Strom is in 0.8.2 release.

Comment: This question isn't really about a specific Storm problem, but a more general question about Storm characteristics. This is more appropriate for the storm-users mailing list than SO because it's not about solving a specific problem with your code.

Comment: Figured out that sleep causes a bit problem, in default.yaml there is a configuration for sleep when empty emit at spout. when set it a meaningful value for stream process, it is ok now.